# Detecting chrome headless that spoof navigator properties

Tags: bots, google-chrome-headless, headless-browser, web-traffic

I buy web traffic from several sources (including the major names in the industry) and recently got reports from advertisers that there's quite a bit of "invalid" traffic. They won't share which filter they use so I can block it on my end. I tested all the navigator properties, resolution, window size, modernizr features, etc, and the bad traffic seems to be spoofing everything.

After some testing, I found that using this code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open('/save?' + navigator.userAgent ,'_blank');
});
```

In some cases, the saved user agent is different from the one saved on the top window. Meaning, a visit hits a page, in that page the user agent could be something like:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.17763

Then that page uses window.open() to open a new window and reads the user agent again, and it will read something like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   HeadlessChrome/72.0.3617.0 Safari/537.36

I tried all the usual methods, window.chrome, webdriver, permissions, plugins, fonts, reading those vars in an iframe, etc, they pass all the tests, the only thing that works is the `window.open`, but I obviously can't open a popup to filter the traffic.

Is there any way to detect this type of traffic?